# scrapy: if node contains child node

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following web page:
https://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=Juice&sa_f=search-product&filter=news&suggid=

for each article, I have the following html section i want to scrape the text of  from:

```
<dd>
<span class="signpost-site" data-site="news">News
</span>
<span class="signpost-section">Europe
</span>
</dd>
```

In this case, I want "Europe"

sometimes the

```
<span class="signpost-section">
```

is missing and instead there is

```
<dd>
<span class="signpost-site" data-site="news">News
</span>
</dd>
```

In this case I want ""

The intention is to create a csv and ensure each article has the right tag at the right index number.

currently my code is

```
response.xpath('//footer//dd/span[@class="signpost-section"]/text()').extract()
```

which gets existing tags only. I am unsure on how to check whether or not the

```
<span class="signpost-section">
```

exists within

```
response.xpath('//footer//dd/span[@class="signpost-site"])
```

ideally i want something along the lines of

```
if  <span class="signpost-section"> (exists in) response.xpath('//footer//dd/span[@class="signpost-site"])
then
response.xpath('//footer//dd/span[@class="signpost-section"]/text()').extract()
else ""
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use [`.extract_first()`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1) with a specified *default value* (used when no match):

```
response.xpath('//footer//dd/span[@class="signpost-section"]/text()').extract_first(default='')
```

Comment: I would want all tags for each headline though? extract_first() just gets the first article's